# Cucumber hooks assistance

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

I have the a feature file that has 5 scenarios within. What I've been googling without success is how to make each scenario start and close a new browser. What I want is to use the same instance of the browser I created when the first scenario is run.

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    SeleniumDriver.chromeDriverSetUp();
    SeleniumDriver.getDriver().navigate().to(PropertiesManager.getInstance().getConfig(EPropertiesNames.BASE_URL));
    SeleniumDriver.getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}


@After
public void tearDown(){
    SeleniumDriver.getDriver().quit();
}
```

The code above is are my BaseSteps for my features. I'm new to cucumber so any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you're looking for smthn like `@BeforeSuite` and `@AfterSuite`, i.e. methods that are going to be executed only once per execution, unfortunately there is no such thing in cucumber (in stadard library at least). However, you could consider using **shutdown hooks** to execute some code after your java app is about to shutdown, but I would strongly recommend to avoid doing so.
There are 2 other recommendations that I could give you:

1. If for some reason your tests rely on each other - consider to try and make them independent.
2. There are other BDD tools that actually have things you're looking for, one them is, for example, [Gauge](https://docs.getgauge.io/)